# unexpected fill command behavior

Tags: mesh, edges, faces

Please help with an F-key command problem.

As I understand it, selecting two or more vertices, then pressing the F key should create a new edge (two vertices) or face (more than two vertices between the selected vertices. If I am correct, edges and faces would be created joining distinct meshes if vertices on separated meshes were selected.

I am getting very different results and I have no idea what I could have set incorrectly to cause problems. What comes out joins some seemingly unrelated vertices -- definitely not only the ones selected.

As far as I can discern there are no duplicated vertices.

The pictures I provided show the two meshes I want to connect. One picture with nothing selected, one with four vertices selected, one with the result of using F key. (The order of the pictures displayed may not be the logical order for my description, but they uploaded that way.) I get similar results from selecting only two vertices.

The F-key behaves as expected when I select vertices on only one of the two unattached meshes.

I am using Blender 2.83.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can shed some light on this issue! Please let me know if any further information from me would be helpful.

[image: F KEY RESULTS]

[image: NO VERTICES SELECTED]

[[image: FOUR VERTICES SELECTED][2]]

Comment: You can't join vertices from separate meshes. You have to join the meshes into one object first.

Comment: That did it using "join". Thank you! Not sure where I got the impression that separate meshes could actually be connected.

Comment: In earlier versions of Blender such as the one you're using (2.83) you could only edit one mesh at a time in Edit mode. With recent versions you can select multiple meshes in Object mode and then edit them all at the same time in Edit mode, but you still can't join them if they're separate objects which does confuse some folks. You can also add a new mesh (Ctrl-A) in Edit mode of course but that then becomes part of the same mesh that you're already editing so you can already join vertices to that.